# Does Bivariate Normal have a monotone likelihood ratio?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

In general, with all parameters unknown I think the answer to this question is no. I think this because in this instance we would have a curved multivariate exponential family. Is this reasoning correct?

Now, suppose the only unknown parameters are the correlation, $\rho$, and one of the means, $\mu_1$, then in this (or any other) particular instance does the bivariate normal distribution have a monotone likelihood ratio?

Comment: With all parameters unknown, it is actually a multiparameter exponential family (not curved). If the only unknown parameter is $\rho$ (suppose the means are zero and variances are one), then it is a curved exponential family. You can find this [here](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/expfamily.pdf) on pages 13 and 20.